# Why IEqualityComparer doesn't work as expected?

Tags: c#, equality, iequalitycomparer

Why EqualityComparer `MyEqComp` doesn't work?
It should left in `arr` only 2 elements with equal `Values` - `myDic["1"]`and `myDic["3"]` with `Value="456"`. But instead it consists of `myDic["1"]` and `myDic["2"]` but their Values are not equal.
Function `GetHashCode` returns the same hash code for 1st and 3rd elements!

```
public class Program
    {
        public static Dictionary<string,string> myDic = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        public static void Main()
        {
            myDic.Add("1","456");
            myDic.Add("2","567");
            myDic.Add("3","456");
            var arr=myDic.Distinct(new MyEqComp());
            foreach (var n in arr)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("key="+n.Key+",value="+n.Value+"\n");
            }
        
        }
        class MyEqComp:IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<string,string>>{
            public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<string,string> pair1, KeyValuePair<string,string> pair2){
                Console.WriteLine("pair1="+pair1+",pair2="+pair2);
                return pair1.Value == pair2.Value;
            }
            public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<string,string> pair){
                var code = pair.Value.GetHashCode();
                Console.WriteLine("code="+code);
                return code;
            }
        }
        
    }
```

And the output

```
code=-121858068
key=1,value=456

code=437991364
key=2,value=567

code=-121858068
pair1=[1, 456],pair2=[3, 456]
```

Comment: I think you've misread the description of what `Distinct` is meant to do - it's meant to give *distinct* values, effectively eliminating any duplicates. It sounds like you're expecting it to *return* the duplicates. That output looks fine to me.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, you are right! I am tired, I need to rest :D

Comment: Are you sure == works for your values which seems to be string ?

Comment: I think your own extensive logging confused you. The last keyvaluepair is not returned (correctly), because it has the same value the first.

Comment: @pirela, it doesn't matter in my case now, its just for testing purposes but yes, strings in this case can be compared with ==.

Comment: NoImagination you can ignore @pirela comment - they likely believe this is Java question (where you can't use == to compare strings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Code is correct and works as expected.